# After Windows update, can’t login to Samba share on CentOS VM

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, centos, samba, authentication

I have a CentOS VM, running as a guest in VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host.
I have set up a Samba share in CentOS and configured it to work using host-only adapter created in VirtualBox->setting->network->adpater 2.
In `smb.conf` I have a [shared]

```
[shared]
   comment = shared
   path = /home/shared
   guest ok = no
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
```

At Windows side.  I use
`net use h: \\x.x.x.x\shared` to access it.  Where x.x.x.x is the VirtualBox Linux local network IP address.  Something like 192.168.2.2 (or 10.0.2.2).

```
net use  h: \\192.168.2.2\shared      to make a mapped share.
```

First it will pop up a login window let me using domain id/password to login.

It worked perfectly for years.

Some weeks ago my desktop Windows 10 was updated and patched by IT department.  Now when I try to access the shared folder.  It pops up a login window but denies my login.  that user/password are incorrect.  We also login using smart card.  I also use smart card to login.  No success.  I added a Samba user with password and try to login as a stand alone user.  Not work.

Login as those id are denied. login as mydomain\username worked before so it is not `smb.conf` setting problem.

mydomain\username

192.168.2.2\sambauser

What is wrong?

Comment: well, first off, the command should be `net user h: \\192.168.2.2\shared` (there need to be two backslashes before the IP). I would not rule out the need for updates to the smb.conf. if you are actually using domain authentication, then samba is what is providing that capability. or they may have changed settings related to ntlm version, secure channel, or signing requirements, all of which might require tweaks to your samba configuration. without knowing what they did and why they did it, its hard to tell.

Comment: You probably need to ask your IT department for help with this. If you can’t tell us *exactly* what patches they installed on your system, we probably won’t be able to help you.  You could improve your question by saying what domain system you’re using. You say that your login is denied, but you can still ***log in*** to the CentOS guest, right? Can you login to the CentOS guest with a domain ID? Explain more clearly how the smart card fits into the situation. Tell us *exactly* what messages you get.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Oh, and the “obvious” question: Does Samba have any logs?  (Have you looked at them?  What do they say?)  Can you configure Samba to log its decisions and actions? And here’s an idea: Create a second Linux VM, and try to map the share from there.